# What are some alternative answers to ogenki desuka?

Tags: word-choice

I reply with genki desu routinely, but wanted to use a variety of different responses to answer this question. I want to say I'm fine, ok, well, happy, and other different ways to answer this question. I want to use various positive responses.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26107/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27420/9831 /

Comment: @Chocolate, my question focuses on how to answer the question with numerous positive responses, it's slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a lot of possible generally positive responses to "ogenki desu ka":

> the standard "(hai,) genki desu." meaning "I'm fine/I'm energetic."
>   "ma ma desu" meaning "I'm so-so."
>   "kekko ii desu yo." meaning "I'm pretty good."
>   "ii kibun desu." meaning "I'm feeling good."
>   "saikou (ni ii kibun desu)" meaning "I'm feeling awesome!"

there are variations on these, and the list is hardly exhaustive, so I'm sure other people will chime in with other examples.

The issue with these other ways of responding is that they are usually said with the intention of getting the other person to ask you what's going on, in other words, to start a conversation about what is happening in your life.

Just like with English speakers, where the set phrase is "How are you?" "I'm fine." is designed as a casual greeting that shows you're neither ignoring or being ignored, "O genki desu ka" "genki desu" is just how a Japanese person greets and gets on with their day, minimal fuss. Any other replies will draw people into a conversation, so if that is NOT your goal, you might want to think about whether you really want to change up the greeting or not.

Comment: ,very helpful response. Have you been in Japan long?

Comment: 「お元気ですか」って言われて「いい気分です」とか「最高にいい気分です」とかいう人見たことないんですけど・・

Comment: @Chocolate,たすけてくれてありがとう

Comment: @Chocolate , I can imagine that these are not "normally" said, but you have not heard these sorts of things, even from foreigners interacting with Japanese people? I don't usually say things as "flashy" as 「最高にいい気分です」either, but Jack asked for possibilities. Foreigners are often more demonstrative than Japanese people as well, so he might find it amusing to "stand out" by giving responses that are a little too "genki". His reason for asking in the first place seemed to be that he was tired of the "same old" response...

Comment: @JACK , I've been in Japan since March of 2002. After studying Japanese for 3 years in the states. I've kind of "coasted" on my Japanese ability since then, not really being diligent about it, trying to emulate speech patterns and phrases, and learning new words and constructs by direct experience rather than from formal study. It does leave knowledge gaps though...

Comment: @ericfromabeno,okay, hope to see you on the chatsite too.

Comment: I'm not much for chat lately... My Japanese reading skills are sub-par, and even in English I tend to think a long time before setting something down in type...

Comment: @ericfromabeno お元気ですか is not a phrase to ask for 気分 or feeling but if they had sickness or some troubles while you haven't seen them.

Comment: @user4092 .... sorry, my situation is unique, I keep forgetting about that... I get asked "ogenki desu ka" every day, because I work at more than a dozen different locations and only see people at each place once a month. So i may have accidentally gotten into the mindset of "it's a daily greeting" ...

Comment: `you have not heard these sorts of things, even from foreigners interacting with Japanese people?` -- ないですけど・・・仮にあっても、そんなの参考にしたり、お手本としておススメしたりしませんよね・・・

Answer (score 4):

One common/typical response is:

> はい、おかげさまで。